# How to set the date in angular reactive forms using patchValue

Tags: angular, angular7, bootstrap-datepicker

I'm trying to set the value of the datepicker control with time. Not able to accomplish

Tried converting to desired format

`app.component.html`:

```html
<input id="requestdate" type="date" class="form-control" formControlName="requestdate"
```

`app.component.ts`:

```js
ngOnInit() {

this.loginForm = this.formBuilder.group({ 
                    requestdate : ['']
                  })

let date = new Date()
date = date.toLocaleDateString().substring(0,10)

this.loginForm.get('requestdate').patchValue(date)


}
```

Not able to see the transformed date

Comment: Are you using any libraries for the input?

Comment: No, not using any libraries. Default html input of type date

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You seem to have used the wrong syntax while reassigning the `date` variable. Since it was initialized as a `Date`, it won't accept a string in the format that you're supplying it in. You'll have to use the `YYYY-MM-DD` format.

Try this:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  loginForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loginForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      requestdate: ['']
    })
    this.loginForm.get('requestdate').patchValue(this.formatDate(new Date()));
  }

  private formatDate(date) {
    const d = new Date(date);
    let month = '' + (d.getMonth() + 1);
    let day = '' + d.getDate();
    const year = d.getFullYear();
    if (month.length < 2) month = '0' + month;
    if (day.length < 2) day = '0' + day;
    return [year, month, day].join('-');
  }
}
```

Don't forget to wrap the `input` field around a `form` tag with `formGroup` attribute set to `loginForm`:

```
<form [formGroup]="loginForm">
  <input
    id="requestdate" 
    type="date" 
    class="form-control" 
    formControlName="requestdate" />
</form>
```

---

> Here's a [**Working Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-date-input-using-reactive-forms?file=app/app.component.html) for your ref.

Answer (score 0):

For the date transformation to yyyy-MM-dd you could also use the `.toJSON()` method:

```js
private formatDate(date) {
    let newDate = new Date(date);
    return newDate.toJSON().split('T')[0];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
It will work but not perfectly, there is always 1 day less. FOr 

    private formatDate(date) {
        let newDate = new Date(date);
        return newDate.toJSON().split('T')[0];
    }

But it works perfectly with   

    private formatDate(date) {
        const d = new Date(date);
        let month = '' + (d.getMonth() + 1);
        let day = '' + d.getDate();
        const year = d.getFullYear();
        if (month.length < 2) month = '0' + month;
        if (day.length < 2) day = '0' + day;
        return [ye
ar, month, day].join('-');
      }
```

Comment: You may want to [edit] the formatting on your response, all of it is contained within a code block and that throws off the formatting. Your instructions (non-code) should just be plain text outside of a code block