# Patchvalue or get prefilled mat-input type="datetime-local"

Tags: angular

I am getting time from backend in ISO format.
Eg - 2021-04-22T00:20:00.000Z

I tried to patchValue -

```
<mat-form-field>
   <input matInput type="datetime-local" placeholder="start date" 
        formControlName="dateTime">
            </mat-form-field>

this.addForm.patchValue({ dateTime: this.xyzData.xyz_startdate });
```

But it does not get prefilled.
How can we do that?
Can someone please tell where I am wrong.
As I used patchValue on mat-datepicker and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to prefill the value when the view loads, you will need to use the form initialisation to set the value. In the `constructor` or `OnInit` method of the component class:

```js
this.addForm = new FormGroup({
  dateTime: new FormControl(this.xyzData.xyz_startdate)
})
```

Also, make sure that `this.xyzData.xyz_startdate` is not a `null` value, i.e. you will have to initialise the form once the data has been successfully fetched from the backend; probably in the `constructor` or `OnInit` method.

Otherwise, to set a new value of the date, you then patch to the form control:

```js
this.addForm.patchValue({dateTime: newValue})
```

Comment: Yes I initialised the form. Still it doesnt work.

Comment: Could you please update your question with the code you're using now?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have used the wrong syntax while reassigning the date variable. Since it was initialized as a `datetime-local`, you'll have to use the YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss format.

Try this:

```js
     this.form.patchValue({
        datetime: getFormattedDatetime(this.response.datetime)
     });
    this.form.controls.datetime.markAsTouched();
```

```js
    const getFormattedDatetime = (dateString) => {
        const d = new Date(dateString);
        let month = '' + (d.getMonth() + 1);
        let day = '' + d.getDate();
        const year = d.getFullYear();
        let hour = '' + d.getHours();
        let min = '' + d.getMinutes();
        let sec = '' + d.getSeconds();
        if (month.length < 2) month = '0' + month;
        if (day.length < 2) day = '0' + day;
        if (hour.length < 2) hour = '0' + hour;
        if (min.length < 2) min = '0' + min;
        if (sec.length < 2) sec = '0' + sec;
        return [year, month, day].join('-')+'T'+[hour,min,sec].join(':');
    }
```

Modified [SiddAjmera's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57198151/how-to-set-the-date-in-angular-reactive-forms-using-patchvalue#answer-57199312) for your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a very late answer but @Gopal Mishra solution works good

but since we're on angular there is a cleaner way using built-in Pipes

```
import { DatePipe } from "@angular/common";

constructor(
  private datePipe: DatePipe
) {}
```

then to patch the value

```
this.addForm.patchValue(
  { dateTime: this.datePipe.transform(this.xyzData.xyz_startdate, 'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss' }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

For usability, I created a directive:

```js
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NgControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Directive({
  selector: '[IsoDateLocal]',
})
export class IsoDateLocalDirective implements OnInit {
  constructor(
    private el: ElementRef,
    private ngControl: NgControl,
    private datePipe: DatePipe
  ) {}
  isoDateValue: any;
  isSet = false;

  @HostListener('ngModelChange', ['$event']) ngModelChange($event) {
    if (!this.isSet) {
      this.isSet = true;
      this.isoDateValue = $event;
      this.patchIsoDate();
    }
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    //this.patchIsoDate();
  }

  patchIsoDate = () => {
    this.isoDateValue = this.isoDateValue ?? this.ngControl.control.value;

    if (this.isoDateValue) {
      this.isoDateValue = this.datePipe.transform(
        this.isoDateValue,
        'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss'
      );
      this.ngControl.control.patchValue(this.isoDateValue);
    }
  };
}
```

Then in datetime-local

```html
<input
    type="datetime-local"
    class="form-control form-control-sm"
    formControlName="my_date_local"
    IsoDateLocal
/>
```